# c# click on button and copy a default image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

This is my first time making app for windows and working with C#.

I was wondering how can I make a button that copies an image specific for that button? (think emoticons)

I am building an app for sending pictures with SMS or chat.  When the user clicks on the picture (button) I want the button's picture to be copied for use in the SMS or chat.

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: See: [Add Image to Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701386/c-xaml-add-image-to-button?rq=1) and [Get BitmapImage from Xaml Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507820/how-to-get-bitmapimage-in-codebehind-from-the-image-tag-in-xaml-in-wpf-silverlig)

Comment: Is not I'm looking for sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to send image inside SMS. For chat you'll need to create special socket like program which will accept binary data during chat (e.g. WhatsApp). However, you can create an email and attach the image to that mail message. Let me know if I answered the question correctly.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if you ever saw that apps with pictures and you click on them and it copy that image and you can just paste where ever you want. But I was thinking of making only a gallery of images and user can select them self's what you suggest is the best options?